# Convergence of $\sum_{\omega \in \Lambda\setminus \{0\}} \frac{1}{\omega^k}$ for $k > 2$ and any lattice $\Lambda\subset \Bbb C$

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation, modular-forms, integer-lattices, absolute-convergence

This post is about the absolute convergence of the Eisenstein series ([see these notes](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2015/LectureNotes15.pdf)), i.e., for any lattice $\Lambda \subset \mathbb C$ and $k > 2$,

$$\sum_{\substack{\omega\in \Lambda\\\omega \ne 0}} \frac{1}{\omega^k}$$
converges absolutely.

---

> Let $\delta$ be the minimum distance between points in $\Lambda$, i.e.,
> $$\delta := \inf\{|\lambda_1 - \lambda_2|: \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \Lambda\}$$
> Consider the annulus
> $$A = A(r,\delta) := \left\{z\in \Bbb C: r \le |z| < r + \frac\delta 2 \right\}$$
> $\hspace{4cm}$[image]
>
> Any two distinct lattice points in $A$ must be separated by an arc of length at least $δ/2$
> when measured along the inner rim of $A$. It follows that $A$ contains at most $4πr/δ$ lattice points. The number of lattice points in the annulus $\{ω : n ≤ |ω| < n + 1\}$ is therefore bounded by $cn$, where $c \le (2/δ)(4πr/δ) = 8π/δ^2$. We then have
> $$\sum_{\substack{\omega\in \Lambda\\ \omega\ne 0}} \frac{1}{|\omega|^k} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{cn}{n^k} = c\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{1-k} < \infty$$
> since $k > 2$.

1. Why must any two distinct lattice points in $A$ be separated by an arc of length at least $δ/2$, when measured along the inner rim of $A$? If this is true, it is clear that $A$ contains at most $\frac{2\pi r}{\delta/2} = \frac{4πr}{δ}$ lattice points.
2. Lastly, how does one see that number of lattice points in the annulus $\{ω : n ≤ |ω| < n + 1\}$ is bounded by $cn$, where $c \le (2/δ)(4πr/δ) = 8π/δ^2$? Of course, the constant $c = c(\Lambda)$ depends on the lattice.

I understand all the other details. A pictorial proof/explanation might help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1. Draw two half-lines from the center of the annulus, and assume that they cut a subdomain of your annulus such that the length of the innermost arc is less than $\delta/2$. Then by “filling in” the innermost arc you can have a convex domain, where you can study the maximum of the strictly convex distance function (and see that it is less than $\delta$, so the area can’t contain two distinct points of the lattice). The statement of 2. is wrong as is, but the idea is correct: just add the point counts of many annuli with width $\delta/2$.

Comment: @Aphelli I'm not sure I follow. Could you add more details? A part of the convex domain we construct is outside $A$, isn't it? What's the distance function? Is it $d(x_0, \cdot): z \mapsto d(x_0,z)$ after fixing some $x_0 \in S$ in the convex domain $S$?

Comment: The distance function is $(x,y) \in D^2 \longmapsto d(x,y)$. Indeed, our domain $D$ is not contained in $A$, but since we want to show that the maximum of the distance on (basically) $D \cap A$ is less than $\delta$, it’s enough to show that the maximum of the distance on $D$ is less than $\delta$.